# How do I allow deprecated features?

Tags: rust, deprecated

I have a Rust project that depends on string_cache, which requires nightly. However, the latest version of nightly is refusing to compile due to deprecated features:

```
$ cargo build
   Compiling string_cache v0.1.0 (https://github.com/servo/string-cache#45f19068)
/home/wilfred/.multirust/toolchains/nightly/cargo/git/checkouts/string-cache-efa5c30b1d5a962c/master/src/atom/mod.rs:65:21: 65:37 error: use of deprecated item: use `String::from` instead, #[deny(deprecated)] on by default
/home/wilfred/.multirust/toolchains/nightly/cargo/git/checkouts/string-cache-efa5c30b1d5a962c/master/src/atom/mod.rs:65             string: String::from_str(string_to_add),
                                                                                                                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
Could not compile `string_cache`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

How do I compile string_cache? I've tried adding

```
#![allow(deprecated)]
```

to my main.rs, but that doesn't change the behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler doesn't impose any restrictions on the usage of deprecated methods by default:

```
fn main() {
   (32.0f64).is_positive();
}
```

Compiles, but has the warning:

```
warning: use of deprecated item: renamed to is_sign_positive, #[warn(deprecated)] on by default
```

Your error message helps point to the culprit:

```
#[deny(deprecated)] on by default
```

You'll have to figure out where the `deny` is specified.

Comment: Aha, you're right. Looks like the `#[deny(deprecated)]` is [set by the library itself](https://github.com/servo/string-cache/blob/45f19068decb55c6e328efc4dcb1544f82aa5b35/src/lib.rs#L15). Can I override it?

Comment: @WilfredHughes: no, you cannot change the code of crates you depend on.

Comment: @Chris Morgan: short of forking the code (where available) and depending on your own fork.